# Calling a C++ DLL from C# with unions

Tags: c#, c++

I am receiving callbacks from a C++ DLL and need to accept a struct looking like this:

```
typedef struct {
  union {
    SXAnyDevice any_device;
    SXInternalDevice internal;
    SXExternalDevice external;
  }
  int device_type;
} SXDevice;
```

I have created structs that are referenced in C# and have set an explicit layout but I have a problem with setting the FieldOffset for the device_type field as the referenced structs in the union are not all of the same size.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct SXDevice {
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public SXAnyDevice any_device;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public SXInternalDevice internal_device;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public SXExternalDevice external_device;
    [FieldOffset(**Not sure how to handle this**)]
    public int device_type;
}
```

Any ideas how best to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to quickly get the offset:** use the value returned by `offsetof(SXDevice, device_type)` in C++.

Explanation for the offset:

An union takes as much space as it's biggest component.

Let `maxSize` = `max(sizeof(SXAnyDevice), sizeof(SXInternalDevice), sizeof(SXExternalDevice))`

Now everything depends on how it's configured on the C++ side:

- If there is no padding (`#pragma pack(1)`), then offset of `device_type` will be simply equal to `maxSize`
- If there's padding, align `maxSize` to the next pack boundary

From the [`#pragma pack` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx):

> Specifies the value, in bytes, to be used for packing. If the compiler option /Zp is not set for the module, the default value for n is 8. Valid values are 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16. The alignment of a member will be on a boundary that is either a multiple of n or a multiple of the size of the member, whichever is smaller.

Comment: Brilliant, I will give that a go. Is there any way to include something in the definition of the struct rather as I'm not sure how best to set the offsets at runtime?

Comment: I have the fieldoffset as an attribute in the struct. I can't put sizeof(SXAnyDevice) as the fieldoffset parameter as the compiler complains that the attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression.

Comment: @David Yes, it has to be a compile-time constant. Anyway, it entirely depends on how the C++ layouts the struct, so it wouldn't be very reliable to make the C# compiler deduce that. Compile a C++ program that prints the value of `offsetof(SXDevice, device_type)` and put that value in the `FieldOffset` attribute parameter in C#.